# Relational SQL query

Tags: sql

There are two tables which have a relation via a distinct so called PK.

```
Email     Gender  
a@a.cn    12345  
b@b.cn    12365

PK     String    
12345  MALE  
12365  FEMALE
```

What would a query look like to get E-Mail and the String of the gender?

```
 select 
  user.Email,
  users.Gender
from
  users,
values
```

Comment: May I ask why you are storing this data in two separate tables? With something like gender, why do you need to use a code to reference it in another table rather than storing it the table with the email?

Comment: I did not design the database. Unfortunately I cannot tell you the intentions I just need to get data out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to `JOIN` the two tables. My suggestion would be to use ANSI `JOIN` syntax like `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` instead of using a comma between the tables, similar to this:

```
select u.Email, v.String
from users u
inner join value v
   on u.Gender = v.PK
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd54d/2)

If you are confused about `JOIN` syntax, here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thank you for this. Two additional question: I tried this in Oracle SQL Developer and if I translate this join it doesn't work, while commas work. Do you know how I can select several different of v.String? It's used for more than gender and only separated by PK. So if I use it in select with my approach I only get the first value, which is gender, but I also need "day of registration" for example, which is also stored in v.String and distinct by PK.

Comment: @BenSchnitzel are the datatypes the same in both tables?  As far as adding more fields, you should be able to add them to to the select list if they are in the same tables, if not then you will have to add a join to the other tables.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Sorry to bother, but please consider this example: I have a table with values for lists, which are all saved in the column code and identified via PK. Now I want the first code, which is gender and I select v.code but I want second code which is title and also stored in v.code but with different PK. How can I select both? I can't write select v.code, v.code can I?

Comment: @BenSchnitzel it is hard to say from your description.  Can you create a sql fiddle with a working data model?

Comment: Here's your fiddle edited: basically, I also want to show the title "DOCTOR" which is in the same column but other PK.   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fcac9/2

Comment: @BenSchnitzel you will join on the table twice and give different aliases to each table --- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fcac9/4

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I meant! Helped me a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

This is what you'll need.

```
select user.Email, gender.String
from user, gender
where user.Gender = gender.String
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't like the comma join but hey

Comment: I have another problem: gender.string is used for oder things and only seperated by gender.pk how can I select those several gender.string in the select statement so I does not only give gender but also other values for different gender.pk

Comment: @JanDvorak Agree with you. It's "quick and dirty" though. :)

Comment: @BenSchnitzel Sorry, I do not understand your question. If you want to select only a few gender.string, simply add to the WHERE clause, e.g.

    select user.Email, gender.String
    from user, gender
    where user.Gender = gender.String
    and gender.String = 'MALE'

If you have other columns in the gender table which you want to output as well, just include them in the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Joins.

In case of **MySQL**

```
SELECT `user`.`Email`, `gender`.`String`
  FROM `user`, `gender`
  WHERE `user`.`Gender` = `gender`.`String`
```

In case of **MSSQL**

```
SELECT user.Email, gender.String
  FROM user, gender
  WHERE user.Gender = gender.String
```

#### Output:

```
+------------------+
| Email  |  Gender |
+------------------+
| a@a.cn | MALE    |
| b@b.cn | FEMALE  |
+------------------+
```